# Improvements in the 1v1 Pokemon Battle Game

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a mini pokemon battle game with some pokemons , their movesets and their stats .

It was going smooth , until a weird error occured in creating the pokemon's typechart ( line no. 44 to 92 ) . Here's the code :

```
import random

print("\n1v1 PokeBattle \n\n")

class Game:
    def __init__(self, name, type, mv1, mv1_pow, mv1_type, mv2, mv2_pow, mv2_type, atk, dfn, spd):
        self.name = name
        self.type = type
        self.mv1 = mv1
        self.mv1_pow = mv1_pow
        self.mv1_type = mv1_type
        self.mv2 = mv2
        self.mv2_pow = mv2_pow
        self.mv2_type = mv2_type
        self.atk = atk
        self.dfn = dfn
        self.spd = spd

type1 = Game('Pikachu', 'Electric', 'Quick Attack', '40', 'Normal', 'Thunderbolt', '95', 'Electric', '35', '30', '45')
type2 = Game('Eevee', 'Normal', 'Bite', '60', 'Dark', 'Slam', '80', 'Normal', '35', '40', '35')
type3 = Game('Charmander', 'Fire', 'Metal Claw', '50', 'Steel', 'Flamethrower', '95', 'Fire', '30', '40', '40')
type4 = Game('Bulbasaur', 'Grass', 'Razor Leaf', '55', 'Grass', 'Sludge Bomb', '90', 'Poison', '40', '35', '35')
type5 = Game('Squirtle', 'Water', 'Water Gun', '40', 'Water', 'Ice Beam', '95', 'Ice', '35', '45', '30')

grand_list = [type1, type2, type3, type4, type5]

print(" 0. Pikachu \n 1. Eevee \n 2. Charmander \n 3. Bulbasaur \n 4. Squirtle \n")

choice = int(input("What's your choice ? : "))
print("\n\n")
your_choice = grand_list[choice]

bot_choice = random.choice(grand_list)
bot_moves = [bot_choice.mv1_pow, bot_choice.mv2_pow]

your_hp = 300
bot_hp = 300
print(f"Your Choice : {your_choice.name}")
print(f"\n 1. {your_choice.mv1} : {your_choice.mv1_pow} : {your_choice.mv1_type} \n 2. {your_choice.mv2} : {your_choice.mv2_pow} : {your_choice.mv2_type} \n")

print(f"Bot's Choice : {bot_choice.name}")
print(f"\n 1. {bot_choice.mv1} : {bot_choice.mv1_pow} : {bot_choice.mv1_type} \n 2. {bot_choice.mv2} : {bot_choice.mv2_pow} : {bot_choice.mv2_type} \n")

if your_choice.type == 'Grass':
    if bot_choice.type == 'Water' or 'Electric':
        your_choice.mv1_pow *= 3/2 ; your_choice.mv2_pow *= 3/2

elif your_choice.type == 'Fire':
    if bot_choice.type == 'Water':
        your_choice.mv1_pow *= 2/3 ; your_choice.mv2_pow *= 2/3

    elif bot_choice.type == 'Grass':
        your_choice.mv1_pow *= 3/2 ; your_choice.mv2_pow *= 3/2

elif your_choice.type == 'Electric':
    if bot_choice.type == 'Water':
        your_choice.mv1_pow *= 3/2 ; your_choice.mv2_pow *= 3/2

    elif bot_choice.type == 'Grass':
        your_choice.mv1_pow *= 2/3 ; your_choice.mv2_pow *= 2/3

elif your_choice.type == 'Water':
    if bot_choice.type == 'Grass':
        your_choice.mv1_pow *= 2/3 ; your_choice.mv2_pow *= 2/3

    elif bot_choice.type == 'Fire':
        your_choice.mv1_pow *= 3/2 ; your_choice.mv2_pow *= 3/2

elif bot_choice.type == 'Grass':
    if your_choice.type == 'Water' or 'Electric':
        bot_choice.mv1_pow *= 3/2 ; bot_choice.mv2_pow *= 3/2

elif bot_choice.type == 'Fire':
    if your_choice.type == 'Water':
        bot_choice.mv1_pow *= 2/3 ; bot_choice.mv2_pow *= 2/3

    elif your_choice.type == 'Grass':
        bot_choice.mv1_pow *= 3/2 ; bot_choice.mv2_pow *= 3/2

elif bot_choice.type == 'Electric':
    if your_choice.type == 'Water':
        bot_choice.mv1_pow *= 3/2 ; bot_choice.mv2_pow *= 3/2

    elif your_choice.type == 'Grass':
        bot_choice.mv1_pow *= 2/3 ; bot_choice.mv2_pow *= 2/3

elif bot_choice.type == 'Water':
    if your_choice.type == 'Grass':
        bot_choice.mv1_pow *= 2/3 ; bot_choice.mv2_pow *= 2/3

    elif your_choice.type == 'Fire':
        bot_choice.mv1_pow *= 3/2 ; bot_choice.mv2_pow *= 3/2

while True:
    question = int(input("Which attack do you want to be done ? : "))

    if int(random.choice(bot_moves)) < 65 :
        print(f"Bot's Move : {bot_choice.mv1}")
    if int(random.choice(bot_moves)) > 65 :
        print(f"Bot's Move : {bot_choice.mv2}")       

    if question == 1:
        print(f"Your Move : {your_choice.mv1}")
        if your_choice.spd < bot_choice.spd:
            your_hp = your_hp+int(your_choice.dfn)-int(bot_choice.atk)-int(random.choice(bot_moves))
            if your_hp <= 0:
                print("You Lose")
                break
            else:
                bot_hp = bot_hp+int(bot_choice.dfn)-int(your_choice.atk)-int(your_choice.mv1_pow)
                if your_hp <= 0:
                    print("You Win")
                    break
                else:
                    print(f"Your HP : {your_hp}")
                    print(f"Bot's HP : {bot_hp}")
        else:
            bot_hp = bot_hp+int(bot_choice.dfn)-int(your_choice.atk)-int(your_choice.mv1_pow)
            if bot_hp <= 0:
                print("You Win")
                break
            else:
                your_hp = your_hp+int(your_choice.dfn)-int(bot_choice.atk)-int(random.choice(bot_moves))
                if your_hp <= 0:
                    print("You Lose")
                    break
                else:
                    print(f"Your HP : {your_hp}")
                    print(f"Bot's HP : {bot_hp}")

    elif question == 2:
        print(f"Your Move : {your_choice.mv2}")
        if your_choice.spd < bot_choice.spd:
            your_hp = your_hp+int(your_choice.dfn)-int(bot_choice.atk)-int(random.choice(bot_moves))
            if your_hp <= 0:
                print("You Lose")
                break
            else:
                bot_hp = bot_hp+int(bot_choice.dfn)-int(your_choice.atk)-int(your_choice.mv2_pow)
                if bot_hp <= 0:
                    print("You Win")
                    break
                else:
                    print(f"Your HP : {your_hp}")
                    print(f"Bot's HP : {bot_hp}")
        else:
            bot_hp = bot_hp+int(bot_choice.dfn)-int(your_choice.atk)-int(your_choice.mv2_pow)
            if bot_hp <= 0:
                print("You Win")
                break
            else:
                your_hp = your_hp+int(your_choice.dfn)-int(bot_choice.atk)-int(random.choice(bot_moves))
                if your_hp <= 0:
                    print("You Lose")
                    break
                else:
                    print(f"Your HP : {your_hp}")
                    print(f"Bot's HP : {bot_hp}")

    else :
        print("Enter your input carefully {in 1 and 2} .")
```

Can anyone please help ? Also , I'll be glad to have some suggestions and improvements in this code .

Comment: Can you show the error you are getting?

Comment: @joanis TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' (line 60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean this error I got, I think I can help you

```
your_choice.mv1_pow *= 2/3 ; your_choice.mv2_pow *= 2/3
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' (line 60)
```

First you need to convert both variables to the same type, if you want to multiplie them.

Here is a litte example:  `new_float_variable = float(int_variable)`

The int_variable is the variable where your number of the int type is stored.

The new_float_variable is the variable where you store the float, that you just converted.

If your int_variable has the value 4, you convert it. If you print out your float variable, the output would be 4.0

Comment: Thanks for the correction , took me some time to rectify it . Can you please recommend some tips to improvise on it ?

Comment: You could print at the beginning of your while loop a ```print("\n")```, so that it just looks neatly arranged. At the end, if you win or loose, you can print how much hp is left. Otherwise I would not know of any changes. It would be nice if you mark my answer as correct, or give it an upvote. I hope I could help

Comment: And If you write it like this : ```print("0. Pikachu\n1. Eevee\n2. Charmander\n3. Bulbasaur\n4. Squirtle\n")```, the distance at the beginnig would not exist.

Comment: Thanks for the first suggestion ; I'm definitely trying to make my code cleaner . For the second one ( providing indent to the names ) , I made it on purpose . Anyways , thanks for this .